# Kivy: move the ScrollView to a certain y

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

I have a basic application and I need to move my `ScrollView` to a certain y.
I use `scroll_to()` but this time, I need to move to a certain position taking count of multiple informations. (I didn't find it in [the doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html))

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    ScrollView:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "900dp"
            MDLabel:
                text: "yolo"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: "300dp"
            MDLabel:
                text: "yulu"
            MDLabel:
                text: "yulu"
            MDLabel:
                text: "yulu"
            MDLabel:
                text: "yulu"
            MDLabel:
                text: "yulu"
            MDLabel:
                text: "yulu"
'''

class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.box = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.box

App().run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need the `scroll_y` parameter. This a percentage value indicating how far 'down' the scroll is.

From the docs:

> a Y scrolling value, between 0 and 1. If 0, the content’s bottom side
> will touch the bottom side of the ScrollView. If 1, the content’s top
> side will touch the top side.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.scroll_y

So if you set `ScrollView.scroll_y = 0.5` the scroll box will scroll halfway down.

If you know the distance of your scroll in pixels you can always combine the above with `convert_distance_to_scroll(dx, dy)` which, (again from the docs):

> Converts a distance in pixels to a scroll distance, depending on the
> content size and the scrollview size.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.convert_distance_to_scroll

Comment: I was looking for absolute y but I do `widget.y / layout_of_the_scroll_view.height` and I have the relative height, thank you for the help ! :)